# How to know the orientation of image, whether portrait or landscape?

Tags: android

I know its an old question and can be found at many places but still I am not able to come at the solution..

What I want is that If I take image using stock camera of my phone or pick an image from gallery, it should tell me the orientation or exact height and width of the image so that I can decide the orientation.

What I've tried till now using stackoverflow is:-

```
 ExifInterface exif = null;
        try {
            exif = new ExifInterface(URI);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);
```

But problem is that when image is captured using camera it gives 6 and 1 for portrait and landscape respectively. And if image is picked from gallery it gives me 0. So I am not able to decide is image is landscape or portrait.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

There is no requirement for an image to have EXIF tags, let alone ones that tell you the orientation of the camera that took the image. After all, not all images are from cameras, and not all image types have EXIF tags.

As a fallback, you could use `BitmapFactory`. Pass a `BitmapFactory.Options` into the desired `decode...()` method, where you have `inJustDecodeBounds` set to `true` on the options. This will not decode the whole image, but it will decode enough to determine things like the height and width. Then, consider the image to be portrait if the height is greater than the width. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html#read-bitmap) for more on this technique.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Will definitely look into this. Impressed that you replied so quickly :)